# Android whole screen gets dimmer or lighter depending on its child view's background

Tags: android, layout

I have been facing a strange problem with layout. The problem is that the main layout have a background i.e. gray color (`#DCDCDC`). It consists of a child which is `ScrollView` with vertical `LinearLayout`. It contains 2 views: one is `TextView` with black background and next is google map.

Now the problem is: when the `TextView` becomes visible it is ok. But when `ScrollView` is scrolled to make the map visible whole screen gets dimmer which is not desirable from the consistency point of view.

And the surprising thing is that the problem is only in case of 4.x versions of Android.

Following is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/_btn_back"
            android:onClick="clickHandler"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/terms_and_condition_terug"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="clickHandler"
            android:src="@drawable/_info" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="700dp"
                android:background="@drawable/itemlistbackground" />

            <com.readystatesoftware.maps.TapControlledMapView
                android:id="@+id/mapview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="700dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:apiKey="@string/mapApiKey"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And following is the screenshot when the `TextView` is visible 
[image: when textview is visible background is okay]

and following screenshot was taken when map was visible
[image: when map is visible]

If you look carefully at those screen second image is dimmer than the first which is not desired. I don't want the dimmer screen while showing map in it. Please help me out.

Comment: Do you mean the top bar with the back button in it?  Isn't that just a contrast effect?

Comment: yes, Whole screen is dimmer and top bar too(though u may not be able to see it). NO, it isnt the contrast effect.

Answer (score 0):

I cut out pieces of the grey border to compare them next to each other, they look the same to me. There is also a gradient in the first screenshot which gives it a glossier feel as well.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what to say.  Does it have to do with the backlight on the device besides the screenshots you are showing?

As far as the screenshots you posted go, there's no difference in the absolute objective value of the colors.  The comparison I uploaded proves it.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But the problem is there and have been trying to solve since a week but with no solution. Though the uploaded images makes it difficult to realize the problem but you can experience it when tested in real device with 4.x

Comment: So it is the backlight?  Because that difference won't show up in screenshots at all.

Comment: I checked the color values of the background and its same in both images. But while viewing in device its different. Such a weird bug